# Select the proper xpath for a hyperlink with almost same attribute

Tags: xpath

Please refer the attached image,

[image]

There are two href with same `data-callback` and `class name`. Only there are present in two different `li item` with `data-id`:`51028` and `data-id`:`51180`

What would be the exact xpath to select these two hyperlinks.

Tried with `//*[contains(@class, 'edit svg svg-pencil stream-edit-button cinder')]/ancestor:: data-id[contains('51028')]` but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
//li[contains(@data-id)]//a[@class='edit svg svg-pencil stream-edit-button cinder']
```

to select both links and

```
//li[@data-id='51028']//a[@class='edit svg svg-pencil stream-edit-button cinder']
//li[@data-id='51180']//a[@class='edit svg svg-pencil stream-edit-button cinder']
```

to select each link separately

Comment: Both the li contain `data id`  you mean to say @data-id="value" ?

Comment: @JyotiPrakashMallick do you want XPath that selects **both** elements or 2 XPath expressions **for each element**? It's not quite clear

Comment: I want to select both one by one